# Jsoup finds only half of ~9000 <a> tags in the document

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to parse a bunch of XML links from a HTML page. I connect to the page, and parse it for all `anchor` tags like so:

```
 Document htmlDoc = null;
    location = location.replace("\\", "/").replace("http:/", "http://") + "/";
    try {
        htmlDoc = Jsoup.connect(location).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return htmlDoc.select("a");
```

It's finding the page, and loading just under half of the `<a>` tags that have links to the xml documents. For some reason though, it's stopping just under half way. When I use IntelliJ and I try to view the last xml link in the list, I'm seeing this:

[image]

However, the highlighted `<a>` tag appears just under half way down the page, meaning it is only retrieving about half of the desired tags. It's worth noting that this HTML page is **huge** and I'm expecting about 9,000 `<a>` tags to be returned. At the moment I'm getting `4383`.

Is this a common issue with JSoup? Does it have some sort of timeout, or memory cap?

**Edit**

So, I pulled the pure HTML code that my program is pulling down from the server, and this is what I'm seeing:

```
    <td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]" /></td>
     <td><a href="IEHRES30J8M4_1378047310463.xml">IEHRES30J8M4_1378047310463.xml</a></td>
       <td align="right">01-Sep-2013 15:55 </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, this is showing all the necessary closing tags. It isn't just stopping half way through the tags. Either JSoup tidies up the HTML if it runs out of memory, or it thinks that is the whole content of the web page?

**Further Issue**

I found a method called `maxBodySize` in the `Jsoup.Connection` object. I set the `maxBodySize` to `1048576 (10MB)`. The file that is being retrieved is `4MB` in size, however this still hasn't fixed the issue. Here is the amended code:

```
 Document htmlDoc = null;
    location = location.replace("\\", "/").replace("http:/", "http://") + "/";
    try {
        logger.info("Parsing XML Files from " + location);
        Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(location);
        conn.maxBodySize(1048576);
        htmlDoc = conn.get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return htmlDoc.select("a");
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying what element you want from the <a> tag? I've never had this problem :( http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Comment: Later on in my code, I'm getting the `href` attribute from the tag. I'll try to request it directly.

Comment: Could be a memory issue then. How about splitting up the file into sizable chunks and running the program on each chunk?

Comment: I think that's my next option. Although I've just found a very.. very odd outcome which I'll edit into my answer now.

Comment: Edited. By the way, Viva la Manchester!

Comment: Yeah, that's really strange. I've never had to parse anything that large with JSoup though. I guess my only other idea is (based on the assumption that all you want is the link) to loop through the document and check for instances of "<a href=" and use substring to rip out the links. It's very messy though :(

Manchester is sick ;)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll try to stick to the JSoup API. My boss might slap me if he see's me manually parsing HREF tags. Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: Believe me, if I knew it was for work, I wouldn't have even considered it as an option :D

Comment: I never use `Jsoup#connect` for websites. I always download html content separately and use `Jsoup#parse(String)`
How did you get above html code? Is is direct string returned by `Document#toString()`?

Comment: The above code was just made available by the IDE, but I can get it programmatically by using the `outerHTML` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further inspection, I found that my web page loads itself in two increments. I imagine it is because of the sheer volume of data. The last entry in my `jSoup` array of `<a>` tags corresponded to the last `<a>` on the first increment of the page.

I got around this by pulling the HTML down separately with this method:

```
private static String getHtml(String location) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(location);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String input;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while((input = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
         builder.append(input);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

And then calling the `Jsoup.parse` method on the resulting string. This meant I had all the data, and it actually improves performance (although for the life of me I don't know how).

Comment: It also did not help me but gave the confirmation that JSoup is failing to download the large file. IOUtils.toString(URL) from commons-io helped me to get it done successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I tested jsoup with generated HTML files containing more than 50.000 (fifty-thousand)
anchor-tags.

Jsoup parsed these files completely and was able to select all of the anchor elements
and href attributes correctly...

So imho it's no fundamental jsoup issue.

Comment: That was established in my answer to the question.